# connect firebird client to server

Tags: firebird

Just started using **Firebird** with **Delphi XE**. Need some help connecting to the server from a client machine.

I can ping the server, so there is a connect. but when I run `isql.exe` from the firebird/bin folder to test the connection I get a `"statement failed, sqlstate=08006, unable to complete network request to host geith -failed to establish a network connection"`. pinging geith works so I don't understand that error.

My connection statement is Connect geith:geidata user sysdba password masterkey;

This works and I get a connect when run on the server, but not the client machine.
I have made sure that `fbclient.dll` and `gds32.dll` are in windows/system32 folder.

I install **Firebird 2.5** client only on the client mach. I don't see it running as a process in taskmanager. Is there something that I need to do to start the client service?

Both are XP mach, **Firebird SuperServer 2.5**, also have temp taken down firewall

Comment: Is there firewall? Can you telnet to server port 3050?

Comment: Jeeze! I was sure that I disabled the firewall to test connection, went back in and checked this morning and firewall was on. I can connect now, Thanks for reminding me to check. Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a firewall except for port **3050**

Answer (score 0):

Add Windows Firewall Settings.

**Go to Start** --> **control panel** --> **Windows Firewall** --> **goto Exceptions tab** --     > **Click Add Program** --> and select **C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbguard.exe**

same way add **C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbserver.exe** 
now **Restart you system** 
and **check from client to server firebird connection**.

for window7 **Windows Firewall** --> **Inbound Rules** --> **Add new rules** --> add **fbguard.exe** and **fbserver.exe**